# How to use webpack bundle only node_modules?

Tags: docker, vue.js, webpack

I want to bundle my vue ssr `server.js`, include all `node_modules` into one file

I have already build my server and client codes into `dist/` folder

Now, I want to build codes in docker images

I don't want to include `node_modules` folder in final images(too big)

So I decide to bundle my `server.js`

After bundled, I will remove `node_modules` in final images.

But in my `server.js`

```
const express = require('express')
const bundle = require('./dist/vue-ssr-server-bundle.json')
```

It require my `dist/` js , I don't want webpack bundle dist/ folder content only `node_modules` like `express`

only bundle `node_modules`

after a long time wait

I received

```
Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

Here are my webpack config

```
const path = require('path')

const resolve = (...dir) => path.resolve(...dir)

module.exports = {
    entry: resolve(__dirname, '../server.js'),
    output: {
        filename: 'bundled-server.js',
        path: resolve(__dirname, '../')
    },
    mode: 'production',
    target: 'node',
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
        alias: {
        }
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                use: 'babel-loader',
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_module/
            },
        ]
    },
}
```

My folder structure

[image]

**My question**

How to let webpack only bundle `node_modules` and `server.js`, except my dist/ folder?

Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 0):

Webpack bundles all your source code and puts it into the `dist` folder. When you build a final Docker image out of it, you want to ignore the `node_modules` and other unnecessary directories. This is where the `.dockerignore` file comes to your aid. Just like `.gitignore`, `.dockerignore` ignores files during build process. Mention the files you want to ignore in the `.dockerignore` file.

Comment: How to ignore `dist/` folder? I don't want webpack bundle my  imported `dist` folder files like `require('./dist/......')`

I want to webpack ignore all import start with `./dist`

I want to webpack only bundle `node_modules` and `server.js` itself